# CLLocationManager in async request

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, cllocationmanager

I've searched, but actually didn't find any useful solution. My code is

```
public func requestWithLocation(_ httpmethod: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, URL: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> (){
    var header: HTTPHeaders = [:]
    var location: [String: Double] = [:]

    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse
        || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways) &&  CLLocationManager().location != nil {
        location = [
            "lon" :  CLLocationManager().location!.coordinate.longitude,
            "lat" :  CLLocationManager().location!.coordinate.latitude
        ]
    }

    if defaults.value(forKey: "token") != nil {
        header["Authorization"] = defaults.string(forKey: "token")!
    }

    var parametersWithLocation = parameters ?? [:]
    parametersWithLocation["location"] = location as AnyObject

    Alamofire.request("\(serverAddress)/\(URL)", method: httpmethod, parameters: parametersWithLocation, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).validate().responseJSON { response in

        var data: JSON?

        if response.result.value != nil {
            data = JSON(response.result.value!)
        }

        if defaults.value(forKey: "token") == nil {
            defaults.setValue(response.response?.allHeaderFields["Authorization"], forKey: "token")
            defaults.synchronize()
        } else {
            if let header = response.response?.allHeaderFields["Authorization"] as? String {
                if defaults.string(forKey: "token")! != header {
                    defaults.setValue(header, forKey: "token")
                    defaults.synchronize()
                }
            }
        }
        completionHandler(data, response.result.error as NSError?)
    }
}
```

I am getting the warning, that `CLLocationManager` isn't running in active thread, but in my case it shouldn't. How should I get rid of this warning? Maybe there is a way to get user's location without `CLLocationManager`?

Comment: is your `requestWithLocation` function sync call or async call?

Comment: Async, that's why I get the warning.